# Adding payload in packet

Tags: python, packet, packet-capture, scapy

Can I insert image or document (in MBs) as a data in packet using scapy?

This is what I did to send data.

```python
data = "University of texas at San Antonio"
a = IP(dst="129.132.2.21")/TCP()/data
send(a)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do with this?  Build your own file streamer in python?  If so, there are much easier ways to do that than `scapy`

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can send raw data like this.  In this example, data will be ASCII encoded.

```
>>> data = 'University of Texas at San Antonio'
>>> a = IP(dst='129.132.2.21') / TCP() / Raw(load=data)
>>> send(a)
```

Comment: That works, but does it do what is intended ? don't you need to send at least two packets for the TCP handshake to work ? wouldn't this payload be simply discarded by the recipient ?

Comment: @b0fh You are correct, sending a single TCP packet with data is not the same as establishing a TCP connection via the three-way hand shake and then transmitting data that would be accepted by a real TCP stack.  This answer was simply about adding data after a TCP header.